# How to iterate list of lists using jstl?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I have 4 lists in my controller. Product ,Price and Quantity. I am putting these lists in the Result list and passing the Result list via Model object to jsp page.
I want the Output as follows.

Product1

Price1

Qty1

Product2

Price2

Qty2

Here are the code.

Controller code

```
@RequestMapping(value="/demo1")
    public ModelAndView demo1(){
        List productName=new ArrayList();
        List price=new ArrayList();
        List qty=new ArrayList();
        List result=new ArrayList();
        productName.add("iphone");
        productName.add("nokia");
                price.add("70000");
                price.add(2000);
                qty.add(1);
                qty.add(3);
                result.add(productName);
                result.add(price);
                result.add(qty);
                ModelAndView model=new ModelAndView("demo");
                model.addObject("result", result);
                return model;
    }
```

I am trying following in jsp but not getting desired output.

JSP code

```
<c:set var="i" value="0" scope="page" />
 <c:forEach var="s" items="${result}" varStatus="ctr">
    <ul>
        <li>${s[i]}
            <%-- <ul>
                <c:forEach var="s1" items="${s}">
                    <li>${s1}</li>
                </c:forEach>
            </ul> --%>
        </li>
    </ul>
      <c:set var="i" value="${i+1}" scope="page" />
</c:forEach>
```

Any help will be apreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java is an Object-Oriented language. You should **use it**.

Do not create multiple lists of the same size, with a list for each property of an object. Create a class for the object (e.g. named `Product`) with 3 fields (e.g. named `name`, `price`, `qty`), and use a single list of those objects.

Also, do not use *raw* generics. Always specify the generic type arguments, e.g. `List<String> productName` instead of `List productName`.

```java
public class Product {
    private String name;
    private double price;
    private int    qty;
    public Product(String name, double price, int qty) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.qty = qty;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    public double getPrice() {
        return this.price;
    }
    public int getQty() {
        return this.qty;
    }
}
```

```java
List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
products.add(new Product("iphone", 70000, 1));
products.add(new Product("nokia", 2000, 3));
ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("demo");
model.addObject("products", products);
return model;
```

```
<c:forEach var="product" items="${products}">
  <ul>
    <li><c:out value="${product.name}"/></li>
    <li><fmt:formatNumber value="${product.price}" type="CURRENCY"/></li>
    <li>${product.qty}</li>
  </ul>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Thanks alot . It worked. Actually  i am creating one project and all these details will be come from database .I have lots of products there not only mobile.This is just a demo code thats why raw generics are there , sorry for that.And can u  please tell me the reason of so many down votes it is discouraging for fresher's like us.Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

you can just use the variable `s`

```
 <c:forEach var="s" items="${result}" varStatus="ctr">
       ${s}
 </c:forEach>
```

Comment: tried it but not full filling my requirement.It is giving output as•[iphone, nokia] 
•[70000, 2000] 
•[1, 3]

Comment: i want output as iphone 70000 1, nokia 2000 3

Comment: You would be better off creating Objects that contain your data and then by having an `ArrayList<YourObjectType>`  then you can call `${s.name}` `${s.price}` etc

Comment: see @Andreas comment above

Comment: I decided to turn my comment into an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41995665/5221149).

Comment: OK.I will try that.But is there any possible solution to my requirement with foreach?

Comment: @Andreas a damn fine answer